# Which Debian Architecture Should I Use? AMD Sempron 2500

Tags: debian, system-installation

I have an old computer with an AMD Sempron 2500 1.7GHz Processor and 512MB ram. I am trying to build a simple NAS for my home office.

I downloaded the Debian Small CD file amd64 and i386, burnt them to CD and tried to boot from them. After a few minutes, nothing happened. It just sat there on a blank screen. I am familiar with the windows installer how it says "Press any key to continue...." when you try to boot from CD.

So I was thinking that I might be using the wrong small cd file. But which one do I use?

I found this wonderful guide on how to setup a NAS, but it seems to be way over my head at the moment. http://versia.com/2009/11/nas-debian-lenny-raid1-encrypted/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that it's a sempron with only 512 MB of RAM. Go with the i386, I'm not a hundred percent certain if the Sempron was a 32 bit CPU but you won't go wrong using the i386 disk.

64bit version is for faster computers what are made with a 64bit processor... Like Core 2 Duo, The new Intels or AMDs.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sempron#Socket_754_32-bit_Semprons) it depends on whether you have a **Socket A** or **Socket 754** Sempron. The *Socket A is 64-bit* while the *754 is 32-bit only*. Based on the behavior you've described I'd guess that it's a Socket 754.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a NAS, why not just go with a NAS software like [FreeNAS](http://freenas.org) or [OpenFiler](http://www.openfiler.com)? They'll save you tonnes of trouble.

FreeNAS is based-off FreeBSD and OpenFiler is based off Linux. Both are ready for production use.

Comment: I am actually using FreeNAS right now and it works great! However, I wanted to learn more about Debian since I'm going to be using it in an upcoming project. Plus, I want to run crashplan backup solution on my NAS. I found a few solutions for crashplan with FreeNAS but they are all pretty messy. I would definitely recommend FreeNAS to anyone who wants a quick NAS solution. Thanks for the advice @sybreon.

Answer (score 0):

Even if both systems work, since you have less than 4Gb RAM, you will not benefit from using 64 bit. Even on the contrary: your operating system will use slightly more memory (larger memory pointers). Even though amd64 may work, I think it is better to stick to i386 in your case, this is still a bit more tested, and has the additional advantage that some applications (usually non open source applications like flash/skype) work better under i386.

I see only one possible disadvantage: a system compiled for amd64 will use some more processor specific optimizations, and may therefore be a little bit faster for some tasks. But for the packages where you are likely to notice the difference these optimizations may be present in a i386 build anyway.